# Remove code duplication from 2 implementations of delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I've got a ViewController class and a View class. The ViewController has a UIScrollView and the View has a UITableView, and both are delegates of UIScrollViewDelegate.

Both the View and the ViewController make use of the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method, and both have the same code in it. It's clearly a duplication so I'd like to fix this.

The problem is I've no idea how.

I can't extract the functionality into a base class and I also don't think I can have a separate class implementing the method, whose instances I could then use (it's possible in Android but not in iOS). I was thinking of using blocks but don't see how they'd work here.

The method itself performs some changes on the UI of the ViewController/View; here's its body:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    float multiplierYAnimationStop = [Utilities getFloatValueFromPlistFile:@"layout_values" forDictionaryKey:@"scroll_background_y_stop_multiplier"];
    float currentScrollOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    // No case for further back than the bottom of the screen (lower than 0)
    // and if it's higher than where it should stop, keep it at that point
    if (currentScrollOffsetY > screenHeight * multiplierYAnimationStop) {

        currentScrollOffsetY = screenHeight * multiplierYAnimationStop;
    }

    // Scale the background
    float newBackgroundScale = 1 - currentScrollOffsetY / screenHeight;

    if (newBackgroundScale < 0.75f) {

        newBackgroundScale = 0.75f;
    }

    [self scaleBackgroundToNewScale:newBackgroundScale];

    // Move the UILabel with the title and the Button
    float newLabelCenterY = originalLabelTitleCentreY - currentScrollOffsetY;
    float newButtonCenterY = originalButtonDownArrowCentreY - currentScrollOffsetY;
    self.labelHeadline.center = CGPointMake(self.labelHeadline.center.x, newLabelCenterY);
    self.buttonDownArrow.center = CGPointMake(self.buttonDownArrow.center.x, newButtonCenterY);

    // Blur the UILabel with the title and the Button
    float newHeadlineAlpha = 1 - currentScrollOffsetY / 100.0f;

    if (newHeadlineAlpha < 0.0f) {

        newHeadlineAlpha = 0.0f;
    }

    [self.labelHeadline setAlpha:newHeadlineAlpha];
    [self.buttonDownArrow setAlpha:newHeadlineAlpha];

    if (newHeadlineAlpha < 0.95f) {

        [self.buttonDownArrow setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else {

        [self.buttonDownArrow setEnabled:YES];
    }

    // Set the new alpha for the background overlay
    // (no bigger than scroll_overlay_max_opacity, should be scroll_overlay_max_opacity once the offset hits the stop point)
    float maxOpacity = [Utilities getFloatValueFromPlistFile:@"layout_values" forDictionaryKey:@"scroll_overlay_max_opacity"];
    float subtractionFactor = 1.0f - maxOpacity;

    float newOverlayAlpha = currentScrollOffsetY / screenHeight / multiplierYAnimationStop - subtractionFactor;

    if (newOverlayAlpha > maxOpacity) {

        newOverlayAlpha = maxOpacity;
    }

    [self.viewOverlay setAlpha:newOverlayAlpha];

    // If set, move the background vertically on scroll
    if ([Utilities getBoolValueFromPlistFile:@"layout_values" forDictionaryKey:@"is_scroll_background_movable"]) {

        if (newBackgroundScale == 0.75f) {

            self.imageBackground.center = CGPointMake(self.imageBackground.center.x, self.imageBackground.center.y - (currentScrollOffsetY - 0.25f * screenHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that encapsulates what you want, and pass any needed variables (possibly including `self`) to it.

If you have more duplicated logic between your objects, you can pull that together into a strategy object that both object have an instance of (rather than inheriting from). Essentially this would be a delegate for your delegate (which is fine). Or if you have a collection of related shared functions you could make them class methods of some strategy class. But if it's just a single method like this, a function is fine.

Comment: There it was again: a solution so simple yet I didn't think about it at all! I guess I shouldn't post SO questions at the end of the day but rather sleep on my problems and maybe ask in the morning ;]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've only included the relevant pieces of code below for you to see how to use a separate class to accomplish this goal for you.

```
@interface MyScrollDelegate : NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak) id originalSelf;
@end

@interface MyViewController
@property (strong) MyScrollDelegate *aScrollDelegate;
@end

@interface MyView
@property (strong) MyScrollDelegate *aScrollDelegate;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)loadView {
  self.aScrollDelegate.originalSelf = self;
  myScrollView.setDelegate = self.aScrollDelegate;
}
@end

@implementation MyView
- (instancetype)init {
  self.aScrollDelegate.originalSelf = self;
  myScrollView.setDelegate = self.aScrollDelegate;
}
@end
```